# How to shift from one tab to another in a page of tab view?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a jsp page which contain 4 div part having id v1,v2,v3,v4. Every div part contains some contents in tab view. that mean in my single page there is 4 tabs with some contents in each table. When i tried to shift from one tab to another i am using the the technique "pageurl#tab_id". But in this case it is not working. when i click the link instead of shifting form one tab to another it is shifting slightly down.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Working example [here](http://gunis.sk/blog/tabs-examples/index.html)

In brackets are anchors for specific TABs. When you will use any in URL and refresh page, appropriate TAB will be opened automatically. Let me know whether it helped you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bootstrap tab panel examples</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
  <style type="text/css">
   body {
    padding : 10px;
   }

   #exTab1 .tab-content {
    color : white;
    background-color: #428bca;
    padding : 5px 15px;
   }

   #exTab2 h3 {
    color : white;
    background-color: #428bca;
    padding : 5px 15px;
   }

   /* remove border radius for the tab */
   #exTab1 .nav-pills > li > a {
     border-radius: 0;
   }

   /* change border radius for the tab , apply corners on top*/
   #exTab3 .nav-pills > li > a {
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0 ;
   }

   #exTab3 .tab-content {
    color : white;
    background-color: #428bca;
    padding : 5px 15px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container"><h1>Bootstrap  tab panel example (using nav-pills)  </h1></div>
  <div id="exTab1" class="container"> 
   <ul  class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active">
           <a  href="#1a" data-toggle="tab">Overview (#1a)</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#2a" data-toggle="tab">Using nav-pills (#2a)</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#3a" data-toggle="tab">Applying clearfix (#3a)</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#4a" data-toggle="tab">Background color (#4a)</a>
    </li>
   </ul>

   <div class="tab-content clearfix">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="1a">
             <h3>Content's background color is the same for the tab</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="2a">
             <h3>We use the class nav-pills instead of nav-tabs which automatically creates a background color for the tab</h3>
    </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="3a">
             <h3>We applied clearfix to the tab-content to rid of the gap between the tab and the content</h3>
    </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="4a">
             <h3>We use css to change the background color of the content to be equal to the tab</h3>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <hr></hr>

  <div class="container"><h2>Example tab 2 (using standard nav-tabs)</h2></div>

  <div id="exTab2" class="container"> 
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
           <a  href="#1" data-toggle="tab">Overview (#1)</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">Without clearfix (#2)</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#3" data-toggle="tab">Solution (#3)</a>
    </li>
   </ul>

   <div class="tab-content ">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="1">
             <h3>Standard tab panel created on bootstrap using nav-tabs</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="2">
     <h3>Notice the gap between the content and tab after applying a background color</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="3">
     <h3>add clearfix to tab-content (see the css)</h3>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <hr></hr>

  <div class="container"><h2>Example 3 </h2></div>
  <div id="exTab3" class="container"> 
   <ul  class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active">
           <a  href="#1b" data-toggle="tab">Overview (#1b)</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#2b" data-toggle="tab">Using nav-pills (#2b)</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#3b" data-toggle="tab">Applying clearfix (#3b)</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#4a" data-toggle="tab">Background color (#4b)</a>
    </li>
   </ul>

   <div class="tab-content clearfix">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="1b">
     <h3>Same as example 1 but we have now styled the tab's corner</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="2b">
     <h3>We use the class nav-pills instead of nav-tabs which automatically creates a background color for the tab</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="3b">
     <h3>We applied clearfix to the tab-content to rid of the gap between the tab and the content</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="4b">
     <h3>We use css to change the background color of the content to be equal to the tab</h3>
    </div>
   </div>
    </div>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.hash != "") {
     $('a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').click()
    }
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```